# How to use ASP.NET MVC Awesome 4.5 library without displaying trial message

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to implement [ASP.NET MVC Awesome 4.5](http://awesome.codeplex.com), due its rich JQuery Ajax controls and features, into my MVC 5 application.

My problem is that when I run the application it will display a trial message in my all views. Is there a problem if I hosted that application into live server for production and use the Awesome library ?

How do I disable the trial message? Is there any free MVC Control kit available better than this?

Comment: Have you tried paying for the software?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to not show trail message is to pay for 379$ license fee.

There are couple of free, i like this
https://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps...